# sparql DESCRIBE query to get data about linked objects

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, rdfs

I have defined a rdf class for Books. 
Another rdf class for describing people.
The Book class contains authoredBy field which links book instances to people instances.

Properties of Book

`Book
  -Id
  -name
  -authoredBy`

`Person
  -id
  -firstName
  -LastName
  -designation`

For retrieving book properties, i use the following sparql query

DESCRIBE ?book
WHERE
{
   ?book a rdf:Book ;

}

I am able to retrieve all the properties belonging to Book using DESCRIBE i.e the predicate , subject and object. However when it comes to authoredBy field, the above query returns me only URI of the author.

I would like to see all predicates that belong to author as well (i.e its firstname, lastname). Can the above DESCRIBE query be modified to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *all the properties belonging to Book using DESCRIBE*

Properties don't "belong" to things.  OWL isn't an object-oriented programming language.

---

However, you can certainly get the properties and values of books and their authors.  The particular results of a **describe** query are implementation dependent.  Even though the implementation that you're using gives you certain results, there's no guarantee that other implementations would give you that.  It's safer to use a **construct** query.  In your case, it sounds like you want

```
construct where { 
  ?book a ex:Book ;
        ?p ?o ;
        ex:authoredBy* ?author .
  ?author ?ap ?ao .
}
```

That will return a graph of all the triples about all books and their authors.

---

> i use the following sparql query
>
> ```
> DESCRIBE ?book WHERE { ?book a rdf:Book ;
>
> }
> ```

Note that you really shouldn't be defining your own terms in the RDF namespace (e.g., as you have with **rdf:Book**).  You should use some other namespace for your own classes.