# How to optimize sparql CONSTRUCT queries

Tags: rdf, sparql, rdfs

The rdf schema is entailed in question

[sparql DESCRIBE query to get data about linked objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652715/sparql-describe-query-to-get-data-about-linked-objects/25654407)

The following query executes in a fraction of a second.

```
DESCRIBE ?book
where
{
 ?book a schema:Book ;

}
```

The describe query however doesn't give me author details. It returns only properties belonging to Book itself.

So i replaced the above query with the one entailed below.

```
CONSTRUCT 
{
?book a schema:Book ;
schema:bookName ?bookName ;
schema:bookId ?bookId ;
schema:authoredBy ?author .
?author a schema:Person ;
schema:personName ?personName .

} 
where 
{
 ?book a schema:Book ;
}
```

However the above sparql query takes 4 seconds for execution.

```
 Is there way to optimize the sparql CONSTRUCT 
 OR
 should we be using SELECT always instead of CONSTRUCT
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CONSTRUCT query has some unbound variables so will not give you the information that you say you want.  Try:

```
CONSTRUCT WHERE
{
 ?book a schema:Book ;
    schema:bookName ?bookName ;
    schema:bookId ?bookId ;
    schema:authoredBy ?author .
    ?author a schema:Person ;
    schema:personName ?personName .
}
```

If you are getting triples for ?author, then the system is not acting in a standard way.

As for speed, it will depend on which system you are using.

You could also try describing two related things:

```
DESCRIBE ?book ?author {
   ?book a schema:Book ;
        schema:authoredBy ?author .
}
```

Comment: How do i limit the number of books returned using DESCRIBE.
Say LIMIT 10

Comment: You add LIMIT 10.

For more control, use a sub-SELECT inside the pattern part.